# How to use JTAG to test faulty soldered chips

Tags: jtag

I have circuit using the ATSAM3X8E chip, soldering only the the chip and is complimentary passives. Upon connecting to it via usb to its native usb lines, windows throw an error saying that it cant get the device discriptor.

There could have many point in my circuit that could have gone wrong, bad soldering, bad cable, bad chip. So i would like to eliminate some. In my circuit i have a jtag breakouts, But i have no idea how to use them.

I bought a [J-link mini edu](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/models/j-link-edu-mini/) for situations like this, even though knowing nothing about them. I downloaded their software but it would seem to be command line only. Does anyone know to Quickly test my chip using the J-link mini ?

Comment: What is a JTAG breakout? What are you trying to do *exactly*?

Comment: @DKNguyen those header pins used for JTAG they are connected to the JTAG pins of the Chip

Comment: Do you just want to plug your J-link into your board and have it connect to the MCU? Your J-Link edu has other software that goes with including the free for non-commercial  Segger Embedded Studio IDE and standalone upload software: https://www.segger.com/downloads/jlink/

Comment: @DKNguyen since i cant communicate to my chip via usb, i want to try using jtag, but have no idea what program to use in my pc, the software it told me to download only has command prompt, which makes it even harder

Comment: I don't know what you downloaded, but the J-link Software package in the links I sent you has a bunch of GUI utilities. You can use most of them to try and connect to the MCU just to verify the connection. J-Flash Lite is probably the simplest. The Segger IDE is already set up to connect via the J-Link as well so you can use that too to verify the connection.

Comment: @Jakequin - Hi, (a) You said you are using the "*ATSAM38E*". Do you mean the ATSAM3X8E? (b) You don't mention doing any programming of the MCU, before trying (and failing) to get Windows to recognise it using USB. In that case the MCU is unprogrammed, so that would explain why Windows doesn't recognise it, wouldn't it?

Comment: @SamGibson I have read that it is already flashed out of the factory. But i was skeptical about that. If so do you know a guide on how to flash it? i am still installing the program DKNguyen linked.

Comment: @DKNguyen there seem to be no obvious way to upload through the chip on the studio

Comment: @Jakequin In Studio, "Target" menu. Top right. The out-of-factory flash you are talking about is probably a bootloader.

Comment: "I have read that it is already flashed out of the factory" - what exactly are you expecting it to be flashed with?

Comment: Remember that JTAG can only test the connection between a pin and a pcb trace if the pcb trace is either: connected to another pin in the boundary scan chain, if the trace is connected to VCC or ground, or if the trace is connected to a pull-up resistor. Here is some more information about what JTAG can detect: [link](https://www.xjtag.com/about-jtag/what-is-jtag/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a J-Link EDU mini there are several ways to check. One that i have found is using the Atmel Studio 7. Upon opening the program navigate to Tools > Device Programing or Ctrl + Shift + P. Then select the tool to J-Link ( assuming you have installed the drivers already for jlink), Device to ATSAM3X8E, Interface to JTAG. You may then click the "read" button on the device signature. to test your chip.

Although unreleated to the question but, what happened why windows could not get device discriptor is because i mistakenly seat the chip by 90 degrees. Turns out its not the big circle that is the indicator for pin 1 but there is a smaller circle on a different side.